# Install Windows Keyboard Layout from Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-layout

How can I install a different keyboard layout from the command-line, specifically the [Colemak](http://colemak.com) keyboard layout?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can do the job, but as part of the Windows OEM Preinstallation Kit (OPK) and Automated Installation Kit (AIK) the [IntlCfg utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722068%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) can set input locales from the command line.

As per the link above, the `inputlocale` parameter should allow you to change the keyboard layout as long as it's supported. You just pass it the hexadecimal value of the keyboard you would like to use.

Hope this helps.